# Can't write or download to SFTP on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: linux, sftp, openssh

I'm having a problem setting up SFTP with an Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS x64.

I use openSSH with public key authentication, I can login with SSH perfectly with the keys no problem. I can also connect to the FTP server, but I can't write, download or any files from the folder.

#### Users:

```
thomas
thomas_filetransfer (home directory is "/" and is part of group "filetransfer")
```

#### Groups:

```
 filetransfer
```

#### `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

Not all, just the essentials for SFTP configuration:

```
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
LogLevel VERBOSE
PermitRootLogin no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys #might be the problem?

IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
X11Forwarding no
UsePAM no
UseDNS no
AllowUsers thomas thomas_filetransfer

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group filetransfer
        ChrootDirectory /var/www
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

#### File permissions:

```
/var/www = owner = root, group = root, permissions = rwxr-x--- (750)
/etc/ssh = owner = root, group = root, permissions = rwxr-xr-x (755)
/etc/ssh/authorized_keys = owner = root, group = root, permissions = -rw-r--r-- (600)
```

And again, SSH is working perfectly. I set up the private and public keys and they work, SFTP login works also, but when I try to upload/download a file, it get's wrong.

When I authenticate with my ssh box from a remote box I found this in my /var/log/auth.log file, don't know if anything has to do with it anyway:

```
Connection from 192.168.124.1 port 54993
Failed none for thomas_filetransfer from 192.168.124.1 port 54993 ssh2
Found matching RSA key: b4:a3:3d:18:b9:30:0c:60:e6:2b:31:47:a9:8d:1d:53
Found matching RSA key: b4:a3:3d:18:b9:30:0c:60:e6:2b:31:47:a9:8d:1d:53
Accepted publickey for thomas_filetransfer from 192.168.124.1 port 54993 ssh2
User child is on pid 849
```

The second line says "failed none for ..."

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ChrootDirectory /var/www` which has a ownership of `/var/www = owner = root, group = root, permissions = rwxr-x--- (750)` is clobbering you.  Try `chown`ing the group of `/var/www` to a group you have membership to and make it 770.  See if that works.

Let me know if it helps.

As per OP's chat, he found the answer in this [blog site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3805455#3805455)

Comment: Still not working, the owner is now root, and the group is now filetransfer. I can still connect to the SFTP but when I try to create a folder I get "permission denied". I checked the log file and there is nothing special in it, it doesn't give any information when I try to create the folder, although I found this when authenticating with SFTP, dunno if it matters: Failed none for thomas_filetransfer from 192.168.124.1 port 54993 ssh2

Comment: I forgot to add "sudo chmod 770 /var/www" but now I can't access my SFTP anymore at all.

Comment: Hmm.... it seems that was my mistake.  chmod it back to 750.  Let me see what else I can come up with.

Comment: The only difference I see is that in my setup, I have `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and `ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`.  Also the word "group" has a capital G.

Comment: I can get back into in it now its back @ 750, do you use public keys or just password auth, and protocol 2? I think the problem is, that it the logged in user is seen as "others" not group, although I am 100% sure the www folder is owned by the group and the user is in the group.

Comment: tried your changes, no difference, with  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server the auth is even failing, so reverted that, group with capital G no difference either.

Comment: Hmm... this is a good one.  Yes, I do use SSHv2 and pub keys.

Comment: Out of curiosity, as user `thomas_filetransfer`, are you able to write to `/var/www` without sudo-ing?

Comment: Yes, the owner of /var/www is root, the group is filetransfer, the permissions are (rwxrwxr-x or 775)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2763/discussion-between-mastashake57-and-randomkek)